# Using the URLconf defined in projectname.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, The current path, appname/tablename/add/, didn't match any of these

Tags: javascript, html, django, sqlite

When I deploying a Django project, I find this error:
[The error after deploying project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UC4UK.png)

This error didn't appear in localhost and everything is fine in the localhost. I do many solutions in static and media files but still doesn't work.

***Hint: This error come only with tables that contain the image field.***

*project/app/urls.py*

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import *
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
              path('', IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
              path('aboutus/', AboutUsView.as_view(), name='aboutus'),
              path('blogs/<int:pk>', BlogsView.as_view(), name='blogs'),
              path('blogdetail/<int:pk>', BlogDetailView.as_view(), name='blogdetail'),
              path('blogdetail/', BlogDetailView.as_view(), name='comment'),
              path('blogsearch/', SearchBarView.as_view(), name='search'),
              path('contactus/', ContactUsView.as_view(), name='contactus'),
          ] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

*setting.py*

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

*Example of table that contain image field:*

```
enter code here
class Blog(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='media/images', 
    default='images/defualt_blog.png', blank=True)
    short_content = models.TextField(max_length=200)
    content = RichTextField()
    category = models.ForeignKey('Category', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    status = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    recipe = models.ForeignKey('Recipes', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
         ordering = ['-date_created']
         verbose_name_plural = 'المدونة'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

*The files structures:*

```
Project/

   --- db.sqlite
   --- manage.py

   --- app/
      --- migration/
      --- admin.py
      --- apps.py
      --- model.py
      --- urls.py
      --- views.py

   --- Projectname/
      --- asgi.py
      --- wsgi.py
      --- setting.py
      --- urls.py

   --- media/
      --- images/

   --- static/
      --- css/
      --- js/
      --- img/
      --- admin_interface/
      --- ckeditor/
      --- admin/
      --- colorfield/

   --- templates/
      --- index.html
      --- etc ...
```

Comment: Have a look at [Deploying static files - Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/deployment/). Django does not serve static / media files in production. Wait but your DEBUG is True? Also where is the pattern for admin urls?

Comment: Thanks for your response! I change the DEBUG to False, also i found the problem, it is in imagefield and here is the solution: https://medium.com/@mnydigital/how-to-resolve-django-admin-404-post-error-966ce0dcd39d